# Need a Java program that writes all changes made to a txt file into a log.txt file

Tags: java, io

I know about the new WatchDir feature, but I want the changes made in the FILE and not Directory to be written into a log file. Any changes made to it are written directly into log.txt file. The current code I have: http://pastebin.com/GwURfRbi , writes only the last line into txt file because it is reading only one line. 
I need to tweak it in such a way that it reads a line, if changes is made writes into file,
then again keeps reading, and as soon as any change is made, it is written in the txt file instantly. Can anyone help?

code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class LogMonitor { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:/test.txt"); 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
        while (true) { 
            String line = br.readLine(); 
            if (line == null) {
                Thread.sleep(1*1000); 
            } else { 
                byte[] y = line.getBytes(); 
                File g = new File("D:/abc.txt"); 
                OutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(g); 
                f.write( y );
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: "writes only the last line into txt file because it is reading only one line" no, it is writing only the last line because it overwrites the result file with each line.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what your requirements are, but it sounds like this won't be possible unless you monitor a file that is on a custom file system that provides that sort of logging.

Comment: BTW: `public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception` you really want to make your main method throw _any_ Exception instead of properly handling them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you did not set the append boolean to true in your OutputStream. Try this:

```
OutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(g, true);
```

so that it appends the line instead of overwriting the whole file.